# Continuity Must Hold in an Entire Open Set?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Claim: If a function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous at $\vec a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, it is continuous in some open ball around $\vec a$.

Is this claim false? In other words, is it possible for a function to be continuous at a single point $\vec a$ only, but not in the points around $\vec a$?

Comment: You asked two questions: «is this claim correct?» and (essentially) «is this claim false?», which have opposite answers! Now people write answers which start with «Yes., blah» and it is all unnecessarily confusing

Comment: Edited to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Your question title is still asking the opposite question as your last paragraph.

Comment: I'm thinking of changing it to "Existence of a Case for Continuity not over an Entire Open Set". Would you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } x \in \mathbb Q \\
0 & \mbox{if } x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \end{cases}$$
is continuous at $x = 0$ and discontinuous elsewhere (sequence definition of continuity helps here).

Comment: You beat me by just a moment with exactly this example. NB that since $|f(x)| \leq |x|$, one can just as well show continuity at $x = 0$ using the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition, in particular taking $\epsilon = \delta$.

Comment: I was about to make an edit that proves continuity at $x = 0$ using $\delta - \varepsilon$ but decided not to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, consider the function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$ if $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=-x$ otherwise. You can even improve this example to obtain a function that is differentiable at a point but no continuous at any other point.

Comment: yes Amitai, something like that :)

Comment: Would be cool if you could show the second example too!

Comment: @Mehrdad: I believe $g(x) = x^2$ for $x \in \mathbb Q$, $g(x) = -x^2$ otherwise, should qualify.